# How to return a 1 2 3 4 5 ... pattern in JavaScript but with the following number starting on a new line?

Tags: javascript, loops, console

Expected output :

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
...
```

What I tried (and many other not working things) :

```
let line = "";

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  line = line + " " + i;
  console.log(line);
}
```

What I get :

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
...
```

This is what comes closer to the expected result, but I can't figure out how to start each new line with the following number rather than 1.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Gauss sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes) for [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), where all numbers from `1` to `n` is

```
n * (n + 1) / 2
```

as max value of each line and take a nested looping.

```js
let lines = 10,
    value = 1;

for (let i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {
    let line = '',
        l = (i * (i + 1)) / 2;
    while (value <= l) line += (line && ' ') + value++;
    console.log(line);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```